# Wordpress Admin Panel White screen death with a text "Error"

Tags: php, wordpress

when I login to my wordpress dashboard, some pages work! All other pages are showing a white screen death with a message saying "error".
I have tried replacing wp-includes, wp-admin and other folders to make sure that files do not have issues. Any idea how this happens?

Comment: It could be a theme error...Without a full PHP error, it's going to be difficult to help you.

Comment: can you tell me which page/s are working and which are not. No need complete list. Just few for get an idea

Comment: There is too little information. Can you provide log output from: Wordpress itself (including access log of the server that might show 404 or 500 errors) and the browser console? Have you tested on different browsers? Which browser extensions do you have installed? Have you tried after disabling all browser extensions?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have replaced all the files except wp-content folder and wp-config.php one again and it upgraded the database. Now it works well :) Not sure why it didnt fix before!

Comment: @rnevius yes, you are right thank you. @saifudeen-malik turn on debug in `wp-config.php` to see if any more details appear